# C Makefile collect2: error:

Tags: c, gcc

Processor.c

```
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include"Process_struct.h"

sem_t empty;//semaphores
#define MAX_PROCS 5
#define EXIT 1
#define TRUE 1

char outbaseStr [100];
int numProcessors;
FILE *outLog=NULL;
FILE *file=NULL;
FILE *outFile=NULL;
FILE *temp=NULL;
pthread_t producer;//Producer Thread ID
pthread_t consumer[MAX_PROCS];//consumer thread ID

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Initialize Data */
    initializeData();

    printf("argc equals %d\n", argc);
    int num_processors=atoi(argv[2]);
    int case_num=atoi(argv[3]);
    char filename;
    char *outfilename=argv[1];

    printf("outfilename equals %s\n", outfilename);
    printf("num_processors equals %d\n\n", num_processors);

    switch(case_num)
    {
    case 1:
        //printf("case 1\n");
        /* Reading in from the text  */

        file = fopen("temp.txt", "wr");

        /* fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure  */
        if(file==0||file==NULL)
        {
            printf("Error: couldn't open the file\n");
            exit(EXIT);
        }

/*****************************************************************************/
//write to temp
        int length=argc-4;
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            if(i%2==0)
            {
                //printf("%d ", atoi(argv[i+3]));
                fprintf(file, "%d ", atoi(argv[i+4]));
            }
            else
            {
                //printf("%d\n", atoi(argv[i+3]));
                fprintf(file,"%d\n", atoi(argv[i+4]));
            }
        }

/*****************************************************************************/

        fclose(file);
        file = fopen("temp.txt", "r");

        /* Create the producer thread  */
        pthread_create(&producer, NULL, get_request, (void *)file);

        break;
    case 2:

        //char filename[100];
        //filename=argv[3];
        //printf("usage: %s filename\n", argv[3]);


        /* Reading in from the text  */
        file = fopen(argv[4], "r");

        /* fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure  */
        if(file==0||file==NULL)
        {
            printf("Error: couldn't open the file\n");
            exit(EXIT);
        }


        /* Create the producer thread  */
        pthread_create(&producer, NULL, get_request, (void *)file);

        break;
    default:
        printf("Error: should be either case 1 or case 2\n");
        exit(EXIT);
        break;
    }

    pthread_join(producer, NULL);


    //displayQ();


    // Create the consumer threads
    for(int i=0;i<num_processors;i++)
    {

        sprintf(outbaseStr, "%s.%ld", outfilename, (long)(i+1));
        //printf("outbaseStr equals %s\n", outbaseStr);
        outLog=fopen(outbaseStr, "w");
        if(outLog==NULL)
        {
            printf("Error: couldn't open the file\n");
            exit(EXIT);
        }

        pthread_create(&consumer[i], NULL, processor, (void *)outLog);
    }


    for(int i=0;i<num_processors;i++)
    {
        pthread_join(consumer[i], NULL);
    }

    //printf("\nfclose\n");
    close((FILE *)file);
    //fclose((FILE *)file);

    if(case_num==1)
    {
        if(remove("temp.txt")!=0)
        {
            printf("error deleting file");
        }
        else
        {
            //printf("success deleting file");
        }
    }

}
```

Process_struct.c

```
 #include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include"Process_struct.h"

sem_t empty;//semaphores
#define MAX_PROCS 5
#define EXIT 1
#define TRUE 1

char outbaseStr [100];
int numProcessors;
FILE *outLog=NULL;
FILE *file=NULL;
FILE *outFile=NULL;
FILE *temp=NULL;
pthread_t producer;//Producer Thread ID
pthread_t consumer[MAX_PROCS];//consumer thread ID

void initializeData()
{
    //printf("initializeData\n");
    //Create the empty semaphore and initialize it
    sem_init(&empty, 0, MAX_PROCS);

//  pthread_attr_init(attr);
}
void *get_request(void *argv)//this produces a queue
{

    prcmd_t *process;
    //printf("get_request\n");

    if(file==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nwe have a file null error\n");
    }

    while(!feof(file))
    {

        process=(prcmd_t *)malloc(sizeof(prcmd_t));

        fscanf(file, "%d %d", &process->owner, &process->burst_time);

        if(process->owner!=0||process->burst_time!=0)
        {
            //printf("%d %d\n", process->owner, process->burst_time);

            if(add_queue(process)==-1)
            {
                printf("failure from add_queue");
            }

        }
    }
    //printf("this is the end of get_request\n");

}
void *processor(void *argv)//this consumes a queue
{
    prcmd_t *process;
//  process=(prcmd_t *)malloc(sizeof(prcmd_t));
    process=pr_head;
    int sleep_time=process->burst_time;

    //printf("\nprocessor\n");
    while(TRUE)
    {
        if(get_number_request()>0)
        {

            if(remove_queue(&process)==0)
            {
                fprintf(outLog, "\n->Process with id %d and it %d de-equeue by thread \n", process->owner, process->burst_time);
                clock_t start=clock();
                sleep(process->burst_time);
                clock_t end=clock();
                fprintf(outLog, "\nSlept for %d seconds\n", sleep_time);
            }


        }
        close((FILE *)outLog);
        //fclose((FILE *)outLog);

        //printf("the end of the processor\n");
        //displayQ();
        return NULL;
    }
}
int get_number_request()
{
    return pending_request;
}
void displayQ()
{
    printf("\n\nthis is the beginning of displayQ\n");

    prcmd_t *process=pr_head;

    do
    {
        printf("%d %d\n", process->owner, process->burst_time);
        process=process->next;

    }while(process!=NULL);

    printf("\nthe end of displayQ\n\n");
}
int add_queue(prcmd_t *node)
{
    prcmd_t *temp;
    temp=node;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&prmutex);
    //printf("add_queue\n");

    //printf("%d %d\n", temp->owner, temp->burst_time);

    /* adding a linkedlist to a queue */
    if(pr_head==NULL)//then pr_tail==NULL
    {
        //printf("pr_head==NULL\n");

        temp->next=NULL;
        pr_head=temp;
        pr_tail=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        //printf("pr_head!=NULL\n");
        temp->next=NULL;
        pr_tail->next=temp;
        pr_tail=temp;
    }


    pending_request++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&prmutex);
    //printf("add_queue success\n");
    return(0);
}
int remove_queue(prcmd_t **node)
{
    //printf("\nremove_queue/enqueue\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&prmutex);

    prcmd_t *temp;

//  printf("this is the end of remove_queue/enqueue and is returning 0\n");

    if(pr_head==NULL)
    {
        //printf("pr_head==NULL");
        pr_head = pr_tail = NULL;        // Reset everything to empty queue

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&prmutex);
        //printf("this is the end of remove_queue/enqueue and is returning -1\n");
        return(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        //printf("pr_head!=NULL\n");
        temp=pr_head;
        temp->next=pr_head->next;
        pr_head=temp->next;

        pending_request--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&prmutex);
        //printf("this is the end of remove_queue/enqueue and is returning 0\n");
        return(0);
    }
}
```

Process_struct.h

```
   GNU nano 2.2.6            File: Process_struct.h

#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<unistd.h>

typedef struct pr_struct
{
        int owner;
        int burst_time;
        struct pr_struct *next;

} prcmd_t;

void displayQ();//this displays the queue
void initializeData();//initializes the data for the program
void *get_request(void *args);//to be calls as a thread to enqueue input reques$
void *processor(void *args);//which removes a request from the process request $
int get_number_request();//returns the number of request
int add_queue(prcmd_t *);//adds a node at the end of the request queue
int remove_queue(prcmd_t **);//removes a node for the queue

#define MAX_PROCS 5
#define EXIT 1
#define TRUE 1
```

This is the error I have:

```
    /tmp/ccvDJUQI.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `outLog'
    /tmp/cc4RWdZ4.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
    /tmp/ccvDJUQI.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `file'
    /tmp/cc4RWdZ4.o:(.bss+0x8): first defined here
    /tmp/ccvDJUQI.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of `outFile'
    /tmp/cc4RWdZ4.o:(.bss+0x10): first defined here
    /tmp/ccvDJUQI.o:(.bss+0x18): multiple definition of `temp'
    /tmp/cc4RWdZ4.o:(.bss+0x18): first defined here
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [Multiprocessor] Error 1
```

Whenever I go to run my make file this is the error I get. I don't understand where the error would be so I can't find it and change it. I was hoping someone could tell me what collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status means and where the error would be at.

Comment: What are you compiling? Care to provide more context?

Comment: It means that a symbol appears more than once when compiling. We're going to need more info sadly...what command line are you using for compilation?

Comment: One main c file, one function c file with a header file that corresponds to it.

Comment: Multiprocessor: Processor.c Process_struct. Process_struct.h
 gcc Processor.c Process_struct.h Process_struct.c -o Multiprocessor -std=c99 -lm -lpthread

Comment: There is an error in your code (which you didn't post).

Comment: You need to at least post the code which defines `outLog`, `file`, `outFile`, `temp`

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, it looks like you're trying to compile header files

> gcc Processor.c Process_struct.h Process_struct.c -o Multiprocessor -std=c99 -lm -lpthread

A header file is included in a `.c` file and not compiled separately. Your command line should more look like

> gcc Processor.c Process_struct.c -o Multiprocessor -std=c99 -lm -lpthread

---

Another source of this kind of errors, is when you define variables in a header file and include the header file in multiple source files, e.g. in `Process_struct.h`

```
FILE *file = NULL;
char temp[] = "/tmp";
```

When you include this header file in `Processor.c` *and* `Process_struct.c`, you define these variables in both sources and as a consequence get multiple defined variables.

To fix this, you must not define, but only declare the variables in the header file. You can then define them in one source file, e.g.

`Process_struct.h`:

```
extern FILE *file;
extern char temp[];
```

and in `Process_struct.c`:

```
FILE *file = NULL;
char temp[] = "/tmp";
```

---

Yet another source of `multiple definitions` is just that, you have defined the same variable in multiple places. This means when you have

Processor.c:

```
FILE *file = NULL;
char temp[] = "/tmp";
```

Process_struct.c:

```
FILE *file = NULL;
char temp[] = "/tmp";
```

you will get this error. The fix for this depends on your intention. If these variables are local to the file (independent from each other) narrow their scope to the file by prefixing with `static`

```
static FILE *file = NULL;
static char temp[] = "/tmp";
```

However, if you want to share the variables between these two sources, you must keep one definition and make the other one a declaration only. Better yet, move the declaration to a header file and keep the definition in only one source file, as in the second part above.

---

In any case, you should structure your makefile a bit differently. Use the built-in rules as much as possible, see [Using Implicit Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules). E.g.

```
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -pthread
LDLIBS = -lm -lpthread
OBJS = Processor.o Process_struct.o

Multiprocessor: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS)
```

Comment: Then you must show the source you have. Maybe you have a definitions instead of declarations in your header file. When you include definitions multiple times you get these error messages at link time. Edit the question and add the source code.

Comment: I only have my definitions and function calls in my header file and is called in my C files

Comment: If you have definitions in your header file, then that is the reason for the error. Please see updated answer.

Comment: what about having static variables in a header file?
Would that give an error too??

Comment: If you mean variables with file local scope, e.g. `static int foo = 5;`, this won't result in a multiple definitions error. But keep in mind, that now you have multiple *independent* variables. And even though it doesn't hurt, it's still advisable to keep definitions in the source and not the header files.

Comment: I just added my header file code to help view the code and see if the error lies in that file @Olaf Dietsche

Comment: In your case, I don't see any possible multiple definitions in the header file. See updated answer.

Comment: The lines in process_struct.h (in this example) should be `extern FILE *file; extern char temp[];`. Otherwise they form *tentative definitions* and each unit will get a copy (causing UB due to multiple definitions).

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thank you for this hint, I never heard of tentative definitions. Although, neither C99 nor C1x talks about undefined behaviour with respect to tentative definitions (6.9.2). In any case, it doesn't hurt to be explicit.

Comment: @OlafDietsche I just posted all my code for viewing if it helps to understand my error.

Comment: @user3664250 See at the third part of my answer. You have the same definitions, e.g. `FILE *outLog=NULL;` etc., in multiple source files. If you need a variable in multiple places move a declaration to the header file and keep one definition in a source file.

Comment: See that's what I had it the very first time and still got the error. So I changed my code around, uploaded this code and I still have error.

Comment: @user3664250 You have the variable definitions in both Processor.c and Process_struct.c, but it should be in only one of them. Remove one of the definitions and keep the other. Then write the `extern` declarations in the header file Process_struct.h.

Comment: @Olaf the UB is from having two definitions for a single object; the tentative definition clause says that either there must be a definition of the object, or it is as if there is one on the last line of the file (i.e. in either case there is an object defined)

Comment: @MattMcNabb In both C99 and C1x, it says it behaves like a declaration not a definition. From 6.9.2 (2) "..., then the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope *declaration* of that identifier, ..., with an initializer equal to 0.". So it seems to be something between a plain declaration (which would result in an undefined symbol error at link time) and an external definition.

Comment: Declarations with initializers are definitions.

Answer (score 0):

For all user looking for an answer to collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status, remember that it is helpful to make all the variables in your header file a **STATIC** variable. That's what made my error go away so to all other users that could be the answer to your error.

Comment: Note that when you do this, each unit has a separate copy of those variables. If you make them `extern` in the header file then there is one variable shared by all the units.  If you really want separate copies it would be much better to not mention them in the header file at all.